Possible compatibility issue between tagpdf and amsthm?
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} % causes error. Compiles fine if either this line, or the first line, or both, is commented out.

\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}
 
\begin{document}

Hello.

\begin{thrm}
The limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.
\end{thrm}

\end{document}

When trying to compile the above MWE, I get the following error:
! Package tagpdf Error: there is no open structure on the stack
If I comment out either the \DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III} line, or the \usepackage{amsthm} line, or both, then it compiles as expected.
Or if I leave both lines in, but I comment out the \begin{thrm} and \end{thrm} lines, it will also compile.
I am using TeXworks Version 0.69 (MiKTeX 24.4) in Windows 11 Enterprise.  I have used the MiKTeX console to update all packages as of today (June 17, 2024). As of right now if I check for updates in the MiKTeX console, it shows "There are currently no updates available."
I get the same issue using LuaLaTeX, pdfLaTeX, or XeLaTeX.
What can I do to fix/work around this issue?

well currently your only option is not to use amsthm, sorry. It overwrites the tagging code.

OK, thank you!  I did not find that information documented anywhere, but maybe I just wasn't googling the right thing.  I'd also be happy to accept this if posted as an answer. Thanks again!

well it is more the other way round: as it is not documented that amsthm is compatible you should assume it is not. You could open an issue here https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/issues.  We know that this is an open issue, but it doesn't harm to track it anyway.

OK, I understand. Thank you!

I opened the issue at GitHub: https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/issues/83

With firstaid loaded and a dev format, your example is now tagged correctly. Compile the following with lualatex-dev or pdflatex-dev.
\DocumentMetadata
  {
    lang=en-US,
    pdfversion=2.0,
    pdfstandard=ua-2,
    testphase={phase-III,firstaid}
  }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}
 
\begin{document}

Hello.

\begin{thrm}
The limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.
\end{thrm}

\end{document}

Here is the tagging structure in Acrobat.

There are still a few open issues that should be fixed in the next dev release.
